# jqgrid: JQGrid scripts not loading in IE

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

i am working on struts2-jquery plugin . the below snippet is working fine in Firefox ,Chrome .but the JQGrid related libraries is not loading in IE , there by its not allowing to make normal Ajax call . 
In my page am getting values from the user and based on search condition i am displaying in grid . Also on page load i am displaying the full datas in the grid . Can anyone help me with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("test");
        $("#refresh").bind('click', myhandler);
        $("#channel").bind('change', myhandler1);
        });
    function myhandler() {
        alert("test handler");
        dataString = $("#branchmonitoring").serialize();
        alert(dataString);
        //refer below
    }
    function myhandler1() {
        var formInput = $(this).serialize();
        //java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        $.get('struts/onSelectshowBranchDetails', formInput, function(data) {
            $("#branch").get(0).options.length = 0;
            $("#branch").get(0).options[0] = new Option(data.branchList);
        });
    }
//code to refer 
$("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
            url : 'showBatchAction.action?',
            datatype : 'JSON',
            postData : dataString,
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
        return false;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in IE, if you open the debugger?

Comment: no am not getting any error... i fi remove the Jgrid snippet onpage load alert am getting , else am not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the reason , i have added a trailing comma

```
$("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
            url : 'showBatchAction.action?',
            datatype : 'JSON',
            postData : dataString,
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

next to dataString , IE cannot traverse these comma , anyway thank you Justin Ethier for your response