# jqgrid is not loading in IE

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which has Json data and works very good in Firefox and Chrome. When Comes to IE,it wont work when the page load but When I press F12, data will load and then onwards no problem,I cant understand what is the problem.Can anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should post the code which you use or just post the URL to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors, can you show some code? Here's an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105038/403664) that mentions that you cannot have a trailing comma after the last element in the jqGrid initializer. Without anything to look at, it's my stab in the dark.

Comment: I have no errors,I found out the problem as it because of console.log

Comment: Next time, add some code to your question. It's almost impossible to troubleshoot otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As I am using console.log javascript is not loading properly. So I use the

```
window.console && console.log('');
```

JqGrid works fine. Cheers. Please check the following link as where I got my answer:

[IE runs javascript only after pressing F12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602277/ie-runs-javascript-only-after-pressing-f12)